# Why margin computing differently on different devices?

Tags: java, android

I need to raise the Activity up *15% of the height of the screen* (regardless of which screen element has to rise to 15%) off the screen visibility ... I'm doing this so way

**i have custom view**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


/.../


<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView>


/.../


</RelativeLayout>
```

**here I set the option to do so**

```
private void initVar() {
//  Margin set in % of the screen
    int marginLeft = 0;

------>   int marginTop = 15; here I show percent of screen height

    int marginRight = 0;
    int marginBottom = 0;

//      Here we get the height and width of the screen
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

//      Here we set the parameters for our view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    param.setMargins((screenHeight * marginLeft) / 100, -((screenHeight * marginTop) / 100),
            (screenHeight * marginRight) / 100, (screenHeight * marginBottom) / 100);

    mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

and that's what happens when I load the project into the phone Samsung S5 1980 x 1080 it looks like I want, exactly 15% occupied (white bar below is the default color of the screen that opens when we raise a View)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**But when I load the same project in the emulator 1280 x 800 screen rises to 25-30% (not exactly 15%)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**And if you try the emulator with a resolution of 1440x2560, it turns out like this**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

In the first screenshot white bar does not reach the inscription "Front picture", the second takes over, and a third is about 50% of the screen...

Very strange because the formula is obtained for which there is a calculation implies that I take the height of the screen and get from it exactly 15% ...

**Why on one device is 15%, while on the other it is more and the third is generally 50% of the screen ??**

**What am I doing wrong??**

Comment: Use PercentageLayout in place of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Just one thing to add use this (100 getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) instead 100

Comment: @MKJParekh why? i use the mathematical proportion to computing...

Comment: @SuhasB why? Which way your suggest better?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko As per design you need equal spacing  as per different device resolution.In percentage layout it calculate the height of Screen and divide as per give percentage its more similar like  <div> tag in html.